# Error using gem net/ssh <= Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed

Tags: ruby, ssh, server

While using the gem `net/ssh` I'm getting the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.0.23/lib/net/ssh.rb:192:in
`start': Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)
```

I don't really understand what's going on..? I've done my research and discovered [this](http://ruby.knowcoding.com/view/69238-authenticationfailed-error-with-net-ssh-gateway.html) but it doesn't really answer my question..

Is there a specific reason why the authentication is failing? All I'm doing is `ssh`ing to different servers, is there something specific I need to change?

Source:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'etc'

print "Enter password: "
system "stty -echo"
@password = gets.chomp
system "stty echo"

def logged_in(server)
  cmd = `who`.gsub(/[ \t].*/,"").gsub(/\A.*\n/,'')
  check = Net::SSH.start(@host, @username, :password => @password) do |ssh|
    ssh.exec!(cmd)
  end
end

@host = %w(server_names_here) do |server|
  logged_in(server)
end
@username = Etc.getlogin
```

I thought it might be the wrong password so I tried entering the password with the echo "on" and I am entering the correct password, I also thought maybe it's not pulling my username so I used: `@username = 'my_username'` I am still receiving the same error

**Edit:**
Found the problem, it had to do with where the `@username` was placed

Comment: @Jakuje Haha, I just edited the question with details on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with where `@username` was placed.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'etc'

print "Enter password: "
system "stty -echo"
@password = gets.chomp
system "stty echo"
@username = Etc.getlogin #<= YAY!

def logged_in(server)
  cmd = `who`.gsub(/[ \t].*/,"").gsub(/\A.*\n/,'')
  check = Net::SSH.start(@host, @username, :password => @password) do |ssh|
    ssh.exec!(cmd)
  end
end

@host = %w(server_names_here) do |server|
  logged_in(server)
end
```